# what "self" is doing in the selenium python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python ‘self’ explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

I just wrote a code as below with the help of `selenium` documentation, but confused with one what `self` does some methods `argument list`? Why I need to import `unittest` class?

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.send_keys("selenium")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        self.assertIn("Google", driver.title)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: The same thing as with any other class. If you're trying to use a third-party library as big as Selenium is without knowing these basics, you're getting way ahead of yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self` is used to represent the calling instance of a class in case of member methods. This is required so that the member methods of a class act on the correct object. This does not have anything to do with Selenium, but is a general feature of the language.

It is similar to the `this` argument in C++

When a class is defined, the `self` argument is used when defining data members of the class as is being done in your class.

Comment: so from where in that body `class` object is being generated?

Comment: There is no class object being generated in the body. self is also used when defining the class.

Comment: @AshRh `if __name__ == "__main__": unittest.main()` what it is doing in the code? could you please explain?

Comment: That has nothing to do with `self` or the class definition you have included in your question.

Comment: `unittest.main()` is simply calling the main function defined in the unittest module

Comment: what we know for all basic OOP technologies is that without creating any object of a class,we can't invoke the methods written inside that class. But in my above code does the OOP technologies such rules are maintained ? If yes how and from where?

Comment: Yes, they are. Also, Python classes are objects themselves as well. So the rules for objects apply on class definitions as well.

Comment: so in python there is no need to create the object of a class inside the `main()` as we did for `Java` or `C++` using `new` keyword ,right?

Comment: Selenium reuses the `unittest` framework here, and that framework creates instances of `TestCase` classes as needed to run tests. Creating an instance of `PythonOrgSearch` is taken care off elsewhere.

Comment: To create a class object, you need to do `object = classname()` in python. Explicit memory allocation is not required anywhere in Python (as best i know).

Comment: @AshRj: and yes, memory management in Python is taken care of by the python runtime.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Does Python offer *any* low level memory access methods ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters now after the code i written and save it as `Mytest.py`. after that if i run it as python `Mytest.py` will it work? or I need to create a object also at run time for it?

Comment: @AshRj: you can inspect the [garbage collector](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html) state. That's it.

Comment: @user1897085: follow the selenium documentation; I'd expect that to work though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if it works,how the class will be able to work without its object creations?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you again. Perseverance (at this post) did pay off at last. Learned something new :)

Comment: @user1897085: Why don't you read the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).